# What is a compliant box for a range hood in terms of a correction request by an inspector?

Tags: vent, hood

I’m remodeling a kitchen and the electrician wants to charge extra to fix wiring issues with the range hood and junction box.
However, the inspector told me that one of the corrections the electrician needed to make after the rough inspection was “wiring a compliant box” for the range hood.
I hired him to complete the kitchen wiring ( up to code) including the hood vents. 
This happened after I tried plugging in my phone in the outlet where the oven will go and discovered it didn’t work.
Initially after informing the electrician of this - he aid he didn’t know why - but after “checking it out “ said there was a hidden box, the wiring was wrong ( done by a previous subcontractor ? I don’t know) and therefore is an additional repair.)
I want to be fair but I also don’t want to be taken advantage off.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard for us to know what the situation is there; you may have to just decide whether or not to trust the electrician.

Comment: It is not unheard of for a hidden box to cause issues, although one would presume that the electrician tested the suspect outlet after the install. Ask him for particulars related to this "hidden" box, in a non-confrontational way, to assuage your fears of a rip-off. If he can't or won't answer to your satisfaction, cut the cord and hire a new electrician (reputable via referrals, licensed and insured).

Comment: Is your range hood box a plug in or direct wire? I assume plug in. If so, is it inside a cabinet? I had one that plugged in inside a cabinet, and the inspector wanted the box extended into the cabinet to be compliant. So if it is just a hole cut in the back of the cabinet to allow the cord to go through to the outlet, it was not acceptable. The outlet had to be physically inside the cabinet, so I installed an outlet extension box, of the proper depth, to allow me to have the outlet inside the cabinet. Now to remove the cabinet, I have to remove the outlet face plate.